# Semaphore for Multiple Users

Tags: c++, windows, boost, process

What I want to achieve:
I would like to count the instances of my application to a fixed number.
if more instances of the application are started, it should only work as a "Viewer"

Her is the code of the sample application

[boost named_semaphore example](http://snipt.org/xnVi)

The problem:
it works fine if all processe are started from only one user
But I get a Security exception if I start the application with another user!!
(Access not allowed)

Somebody can point me in the right direction, the boost documentation is a little bit lacking on this topic  ;-)
What permissions must be set to allow access from every other logged on user?

Comment: Sounds like a "works as intended". Non-admin users should not be able to affect admin users (basic security principle) therefore they shouldn't be able to exclusively claim limited resources. Do you really intend to limit your application to a fixed number _per computer_ anyway? Or did you want a fixed number _per user_ ?

Comment: It's ok that this is the default behaviour, but I would like to change it.
And Yes I want the application _per computer_ and not per user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution

Looks like the docu for Boost isn't that bad :-/
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/permissions.html

Just have to pass the permission and set it to "unrestricted"

```
boost::interprocess::permissions permtest;
permtest.set_unrestricted();
_getch();
boost::interprocess::named_semaphore
the_semphore(boost::interprocess::open_or_create,"test_semaphore",3,permtest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately boost uses default security attributes for semaphore and there is no way to change it. Use `ATL::CSemaphore` or `CSemaphore` from MFC or even `CreateSemaphore` from WinApi and construct security descriptor which allows access for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly a Windows expert, so I can't tell you the answer by heart, but you need to know how named_semaphores are implemented (see "Some basic explanations" documentation of boost.interprocess) and then look up the permission policy for this resource to grant system-wide access. So, read the boost.named_semaphore code, and if they use a file, update that file's permissions, and if they use a system call, read the Windows API documentation for that system call.